# Preserving query-string parameters with RouteMagic MVC

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to preserve a query string parameter, or all of them, with redirection using RouteMagic MVC? I need the old url: **LegacyPage.aspx?q=value** to redirect to **New/NewAction?q=value**. The example below gives me a strange result, **New/NewAction?q=q**, and not the actual value of the query string. I tried all sorts of permutations with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var newRoute = routes.MapRoute(
    "New", 
    "New", 
    new { controller = "New", action = "NewAction"}
);

routes.Redirect(r => r.MapRoute("Legacy", "LegacyPage.aspx"), true)
    .To(newRoute);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted query string parameters to be moved to target url. But I couln't get even yours situation. I'm using 1.2 version of routeMagic. I looked to source code:

```
public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) {
  var requestRouteValues = requestContext.RouteData.Values;

  var routeValues = AdditionalRouteValues.Merge(requestRouteValues);

  var vpd = TargetRoute.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, routeValues);
  string targetUrl = null;
  if (vpd != null) {
    targetUrl = "~/" + vpd.VirtualPath;
    return new RedirectHttpHandler(targetUrl, Permanent, isReusable: false);
  }
  return new DelegateHttpHandler(
    httpContext => httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404, false);
}
```

And it doesn't seem that query string parameters are added to targeUrl.